# Regex - Duplicate HTML links and put something after it

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, search-regex

I have a lot of such texts:

```
<a href="https://mega.co.nz/#![RandomThings1]" target="_blank">[RandomThings2] [<span style="color:#008000;">[RandomThings3]</span>]</a>
```

I want to transform those into this:

```
<a href="https://mega.co.nz/#![RandomThings1]" target="_blank">[RandomThings2] [<span style="color:#008000;">[RandomThings3]</span>]</a> <a href="http://no.refer.co/?link=https://mega.co.nz/%23![RandomThings1]" target="_blank">NoRefer</a>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What **language/editor** are you using?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/screenshots/

Comment: Are you trying to add another link after all that **RandomThings3** stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the [regex flavor in Search Regex WordPress plug-in](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/) is PHP, you can try the following regular expression that assumes you really have some arbitrary text inside square brackets (`[RandomThings1]`):

```
(<a\s+[^>]*?href="[^"]*#!(\[.*?\])"[^>]*?>[^<>]*?<span[^>]*?>[^<>]*?<\/span>[^<>]*?<\/a>)
```

Replace with `$1 <a href="http://no.refer.co/?link=https://mega.co.nz/%23!$2" target="_blank">NoRefer</a>`.

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iR7iC6/1).

PHP code:

```
$re = "/(<a\\s+[^>]*?href=\"[^\"]*#!(\\[.*?\\])\"[^>]*?>[^<>]*?<span[^>]*?>[^<>]*?<\\/span>[^<>]*?<\\/a>)/"; 
$subst = "$1 <a href=\"http://no.refer.co/?link=https://mega.co.nz/%23!$2\" target=\"_blank\">NoRefer</a>"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: @Downvoter: I do not know what you found wrong, please report. Just downvoting will soon leave you without rep :)

Comment: it was not me, I will test the regex

Comment: have worked, but i have to export my db and try to use in notpead++, and mofied something in this code